# Using JS to manipulate in page script

Tags: javascript

I currently have an on-page script.

```
<script type='text/javascript' data-shl-lottie-script="1614423430104">
        LottieInteractivity.create({
        "mode": "scroll",
        "player": "[data-shl-player='1614423430104']",
        "container": "#first",
        "actions": [
          {"visibility": [0,1],"type": "seek","frames": [0,100]},
          {"visibility": [0,1],"type": "seek","frames": [100,300]}
        ]
      });
      </script>
```

I want to be able to interactively manipulate this script to add (or remove) additional actions.  I'm already using Regex to manipulate both the "mode" and "container". Other than using Regex (love and hate), is there some way that I'm overlooking for easily manipulating the actions section of this script using JS? I feel like the actions are just an array of objects, but I can only get them as a string and can't figure out if it is possible to convert them for manipulation and then add them back into the script on page.

Comment: Why use regex? Replace the object in the LottieInteractivity.create with your own object

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the object

```html
<script>
  const myObject = {
    "mode": "whatever",
    "player": "[data-shl-player='1614423430104']",
    "container": "#first",
    "actions": [{
        "visibility": [1110, 1],
        "type": "seek",
        "frames": [0, 100]
      },
      {
        "visibility": [0, 1111],
        "type": "seek",
        "whatever": [100, 300]
      }
    ]
  }
  myObject.mode="something else"
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' data-shl-lottie-script="1614423430104">
  LottieInteractivity.create(myObject);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm going to be modifying an existing script that will have know sections, like "mode" and "actions", but I won't know the values ahead of time. How do I get the original script as an object for manipulation?

Comment: When were you planning to use the regex to change stuff? If you can use regex you can change using script

Comment: I know that I can use regex to change the script as a string. I was looking to see if there was an easier way. Using regex to change the second "actions" value is possible, just not much fun. This is all within the context of a page builder. The end user has a set of control menus they can use to alter the on page script. When they enter a new value for "mode" or "action" the changes need to be made in the on page script.

Comment: I know you know, I suggest you don't just call `myObject.mode="something else"` whenever. Then you can add the script to the head dynamically too

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining well. The script is already on page. I don't control the script addition. I can replace the script with my own object, but I need to get all of the script values to be able to set them in my own object. I know I can use regex to do this, I was just hoping for an easier way.

Comment: When are you planning to do the regex is what I do not understand. If you can do regex on the client, you can do object manipulation

Comment: I can use regex because I'm getting it from the page as a string. When the user enters a new value into the controls form I use a '.replace' to change out that part of the string. I don't know how I can get the script from the page as an object.

Comment: you can do JSON.parse

Comment: Worked - sort of. Had to use regex to get the inner part first and then JSON.parse. Thanks.